# ROS Answers SE migration: UDP analysis

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I use a laser to connect to the computer (with ROS installed), the laser transmits the data over UDP, and I already know the structure of the UDP packet. I do not know if there is such a packet in ROS that can parse UDP data. What is the name of this package? how to use?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/275095/udp-analysis/) by [summer](https://answers.ros.org/users/31948/summer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2017-11-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2017-11-06**:
Do you have a name of the laser (range finder/scanner?) and any links to the documentation for it?

**Comment by [summer](https://answers.ros.org/users/31948/summer/) on 2017-11-06**:
The laser scanner name is Velodyne S3, you can see it at this site:http://www.velodynelidar.com/hdl-64e.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://wiki.ros.org/velodyne - it isn't clear that the S3 is supported, but I do see S3 mentioned in this issue https://github.com/ros-drivers/velodyne/pull/97 .

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2017-11-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [summer](https://answers.ros.org/users/31948/summer/) on 2017-11-07**:
thank you very much, your answer helped  me. this is my required.

**Comment by [summer](https://answers.ros.org/users/31948/summer/) on 2017-11-08**:
Hi again.I also  have some question to ask you. I can see the point cloud by DSR or veloview software. But, I don't know information about the visualized point  data, such as distance, time and others. Do you know that there is a toolkit in ROS for crawling UDP packets and parsing?

**Comment by [summer](https://answers.ros.org/users/31948/summer/) on 2017-11-08**:
What I do is scan the plant with a laser scanner to get information about plant growth characteristics. Should I convert the acquired point cloud data (.pcp file) directly into a ROS node package and read the data in ROS?

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2017-11-09**:
You might be able to rebroadcast the acquired udp data back onto the network with wireshark (which is what captured it to begin with?) and use the ros velodyne driver linked above to turn it onto ros PointCloud2 messages which then other nodes could subscribe to to analyze.

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2017-11-09**:
The other nodes could then convert the PointCloud2 messages into PCL (Point Cloud Library) datatypes which then can be analyzed with PCL library tools, or you could write your own.